# Comando duplicar word en assambler

Tags: ensamblador, x86

Necesito ayuda en **Assambler**,
que hace el comando `DUP` en esta linea

```
APRI    DW  2    DUP(5, -6)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask] ya que fue reportada como de baja calidad! Te  refieres a el comando "etse"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APRI` es la etiqueta

`DW` es tipo word (16 bits)

`2` es la cantidad de veces a duplicar

`DUP` duplica e inicializa con los valores que le das

en este caso `APRI` apunta a 2 grupos de 2 words uno con el valor 5 y otro con el valor -6, o dicho de otra manera "usando words 2 veces (5,-6)"

```
(signed short 16bit)  5 : 0005
(signed short 16bit) -6 : FFFA
```

En memoria de intel x86 los números se guardan con el Byte menos significativo primero por ser de tipo [little endian](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (aunque los mas nuevos de intel manejan ambos endiannes) así que en memoria quedaría:

```
05 00 FA FF 05 00 FA FF
```

por eso es importante el `DW` (Define Word) ya que si luego lo tratas como una cadena de bytes cada 2 quedarían "al reves".

**nota:** lo que no estoy muy seguro es si todo compilador te dejaría meter un número negativo en un word o si tenes que explicitarlo como signed word [`SWORD`](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/DataTypes/lecture.html#T77_0140_int_formats).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-dup

Comment: Entoces en la direcceion que indica la etiqueta se va ver asi en numeros deximales?  `[00,05H,0FFH,0FAH,00H,05H,0FFH,0FAH]`